# Save a downloaded file to storage folder on android

Tags: expo

I've made an app that sends a file from my pc to my phone but I can't figure out how to save it to Internal storage or to a folder I can access. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use the `FileSystem` API. According to the documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/), you need to first install it:

```sh
expo install expo-file-system
```

And of course, import it where needed:

```js
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
```

After which you should be able to use the method [`FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemwriteasstringasyncfileuri-contents-options) and save the file to the [`FileSystem.documentDirectory`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemdocumentdirectory):

```js
FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'filename.ext',
    "some file contents or variable");
```

Look around the documentation about `FileSystem` - there are many useful methods and some examples that should help you.